# Generate dynamic expressions in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a `ngRepeat` element that has a delete button that triggers a confirmation message. I'm trying to make the confirmation message show with a dynamic expression like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-click="delete(item_id)"></a>
    <span ng-show="{{item._id}}_delete">Are you sure you want to delete your review? </span>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to create dynamic expressions, but this is the only way I can get the expression to at least generate in html.

But I am getting this error for all the repeated items (with different item ids in each error):

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'cb0a2a73ede6e3a9d7a58_delete' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the expression [543cb0a2a73ede6e3a9d7a58_delete] starting at [cb0a2a73ede6e3a9d7a58_delete].
```

^ the outputted `item._id` for that item is 543cb0a2a73ede6e3a9d7a58 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one :)

AH,  if `item._id` starts with a number it will get a error

**Variable names must begin with a letter**
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

so `ng-show` bound to a variable in the scope and it is dynamically creating. `a_delete`,`b_delete` will work fine but if it generate like `1_delete`,`2_delete` it will result a error because those are starts with a `number`.

In your case `item._id` starts with number like `543cb0a2a73ede6e3a9d7a58` as you mentioned in you question. so `ng-show` ends with something like `ng-show="543cb0a2a73ede6e3a9d7a58_delete"`. That should get a error because of violation of naming-conventions.

Comment: Can you please help me with this one as well? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26355375/747871

Answer (score 1):

Angular is expecting an expression there that returns true or false for ng-show. So just rendering a String won't really help. You could either define a controller function that resolves to true or false or just write the expression inline, like `ng-show="item.id === 2"`.
But it seems that you want a confirmation dialog before deleting, in that case you should write a custom directive that intercepts the click action before executing it (unfortunately there is no such thing as ng-confirm in Angular built-in).
Here is an example of such a directive: https://gist.github.com/asafge/7430497

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to toggle a message to the user, you could simply make your span dependant on a scope variable that gets toggled, like so:

```
<a ng-click="delete(item_id); showDelete=!showDelete">item</a>
<span ng-show="showDelete">Are you sure you want to delete your review? </span>
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7319/).

However, you probably want to wrap it all up into a directive like @frank blizzard mentioned.