# How to create dynamic expression in ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I have a `ngRepeat` element that has a delete button that triggers a confirmation message. I'm trying to make the confirmation message show with a dynamic expression like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-click="delete(item_id)"></a>
    <span ng-class="{'show':'delete_'+item._id}">Are you sure you want to delete your review? </span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't get the expression `'delete_'+item._id` to show up in the `ngClass` directive. Can someone please offer a solution?

Comment: You asked this same question about an hour ago....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354192/generate-dynamic-expressions-in-ng-repeat

Comment: @FrisbeeBen different actually

Answer (score 2):

Using `ng-class="{'show': 'delete_' + item._id}"` will add the class `show` whenever the expression `'delete_' + item._id'` evaluates to `true` (which is always). You probably want to have an expression next to `show` which is `true` when the user has clicked the `a` tag, i.e. `ng-class="{'show': userWantsToDelete(item)}"`.

Additionally, if you want to add the class `'delete_' + item._id` to the element, you can use angular expressions with `class` attribute, i.e., `class="{{'delete_' + item._id}}"` on the element.

Comment: isnt all expressions false by default?

Comment: @muudless There are `truth-y` things and then `false-y` expressions in JS. Expressions like an empty string, or 0, or `false` are `false-y`, while a non-empty string (like `"delete_" + (anything)"`) is a `truth-y` expression.

Comment: @muudless `!'delete_' + item._id == (!'delete_') + item._id == (false) + item._id == (something probably truth-y)`

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
<a ng-click="delete = !delete">delete</a>
<span ng-class="{show: delete}">Are you sure you want to delete your review? </span>
```

**if you want to show one delete confirmation message of last clicked `<a>`**

In view

```
<a ng-click="delete(item._id)">delete</a>
<span ng-class="{show: item._id==delete_id}">Are you sure you want to delete your review? </span>
```

In controller

```
$scope.delete = function(id) {
    $scope.delete_id = ($scope.delete_id == id) ? !id : id;
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't want to use `$index`

Comment: refer FrisbeeBen's answer for your previous question.

Comment: its a different question, the other one is for ngShow and this is for ngClass, because for some reason the answer for the ngShow question doesn't work for ngClass.